Cryptography's favicon is inconsistent with larger icons
158x158 http://cdn.sstatic.net/crypto/img/apple-touch-icon.png
48x48 http://cdn.sstatic.net/crypto/img/icon-48.png

Crypto's larger icons show Cr but the favicon is CR. I suspect this is unintended (especially as the current favicon is identical with  Code Review's).

I guess it's because Cr is hard to read when using such a small font.

I have updated the favicon(both for Main site and Meta). I used Ilmari Karonen's version, and made the "r" one pixel taller per Paŭlo Ebermann's suggestion.
The changes will go live after the next production build(within 24 hours). You may still have to do a hard refresh to see the changes after that.

Let me humbly say what I think: "thank you"… (love your reading personal site btw.)

I still get CR icons (http://crypto.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico and http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico), dated 2013-09-04 15:04 and 2013-09-05 15:17 respectively. European CDN (190.93.*).

@Gilles it's cached on the server side I believe. you can see the new one if you use cache breaker url. We'll be flushing cache soon.

Generally, as CodesInChaos notes, readability is an issue for lowercase letters at such small sizes.  That said, I just tried it, and it is possible to make a fairly readable "Cr" icon at that size:

(The image above is in .png format because imgur won't let me upload an .ico file.)
Anyway, let me hereby relinquish any copyright claims I might have to this image.  I suppose the original copyright belongs to Stack Exchange, so if they want to use it in any way (like, say, as the new favicon for this site... hint, hint) they're welcome to do so.

I would try to make the r even one pixel higher. But thanks for the initiative.
